# proble while commiting in kaggle

Tags: kaggle

I am getting the below error 80% of time while commiting in kaggle, can anyone help me out on this?

An error occurred while committing kernel: Failed to parse Redis response. Invalid Redis response payload: `{"Key":"timeout","Result":[""]}`

Comment: Do you have a link to the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the markdowns you wrote. Sometimes you have addressed a file that cannot be loaded